# Terraform - getting terraform_remote_state leads to access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 modules ..booted a VPC and added some s3 buckets with output saved in s3.  I then added another module re init then tried to plan

The new module looks like the below.  I need to use data to get the vpc_id.

```
    provider "aws" {
  region                  = var.region
  shared_credentials_file = "$HOME/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "terraform"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    profile = "terraform"
    bucket = var.remote_state_bucket
    key    = var.remote_state_key
    region = var.region
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "network_configuration" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
   bucket = var.remote_state_bucket
    key    = var.remote_state_key
    region = var.region
  }
}
```

When I run

```
 terraform plan -var-file="test.tfvars"
```

I get the below error as a result of the terraform_remote_state block.  I remove then the plans works.

```
Error: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: ZRTM92CVDQFRBF9T, host id: 0HYGuPq9Q7skZLtXvdR3mD6657g4fqUaQQNf2jP2GRcLx1vTxkYhFtyKAiTTLRBrEwECnPf0Y9A=
```

Why?  I don't get it?  How do I resolve?

Comment: Can you add `profile = "terraform"` to your `terraform_remote_state` config.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `profile` to your `config`:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network_configuration" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
   bucket   = var.remote_state_bucket
    key     = var.remote_state_key
    region  = var.region
    profile = "terraform"
  }
}
```